# Select most recent edit of file between thumb drive and PC using python

Tags: python

I work on several computers and need to continuously update text and .py files on multiple devices.

I would like to run a program that scans the thumb drive I carry my work on and compare it to the folders on the parent directory at the main office. If there were any edits since last port, I want to upload the new file.

Comparing the sets of the two folders' files was my first indication of what to do. These lists are way longer than expected, since many of the files haven't changed since I moved them. I'm worried if I go with this approach, I would be recopying way more than needed each time I attempt this.

It seems like an easier approach either already exists (I don't know where to look) or I'm looking at the wrong piece of data (I don't know what to inspect for each file). Can you help?

My best attempt so far is as follows:

```
from os.path import basename as base

def fileWalkIn(path='.',matches=[],filt='*.csv'): 
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):

        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, filt):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
            yield os.path.join(root, filename)

def main():

    pys = r'K:\location\of\code\Python'
    drives = ['D','E','F','G','H']
    for usb in drives: 
        loc = usb + ":\\SDI"
        if os.path.exists(loc): zDr = loc

    ls = fileWalkIn(pys,[],filt='*.py')

    timesHm = []
    mchHm = []    
    for send in ls:
        part = os.path.getmtime(send)
        timesHm.append((base(send),part))
        mchHm.append(send)

    ls = fileWalkIn(zDr,[],filt='*.py')

    timesDr = []
    mchDr = []  
    for send in ls:
        part = os.path.getmtime(send)
        timesDr.append((base(send),part))
        mchDr.append(send)


    ls = list(set(timesDr) - set(timesHm))

    newDr = []
    newHm = []
    for piece in ls:
        for elem in timesHm: 
            if piece[0] == elem[0]: a = elem
        for elem in timesDr: 
            if piece[0] == elem[0]: b = elem
        if a[1] > b[1]: 
            newHm.append(piece)
        else:
            newDr.append(piece)

    return newHm,newDr 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    newHm,newDr = main()
```

Comment: This question seems too broad. Does the code work? If so, you should post it to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead to get suggestions. If not, what behavior do you observe? What did you expect?

Comment: On a more helpful note, if these are all text files, how about using some revision control? Git would make it easy to keep everything up-to-date, and you'd get revision history. If you are really doing this USB-based code transportation with Python scripts, you absolutely should be using revision control instead. Your current approach is a codesplosion timebomb.

Comment: The part that doesn't work is the time created not matching. Many of the file-pairs have differing creation dates, which is not correct. Hence, I'm thinking I am going about this wrong. Really I'm looking to see if other similar code exists, and didn't want to confound anyone with pseudo-code.

Comment: That's kind of my point... You're relying on a *very* easily confused mechanism (time stamps), and trying to create your own solution to a problem that's already been solved: keeping text files in sync across multiple contribution sources. Revision control with a centralized server or integration point is a simple solution with countless software packages available to manage it.

Comment: As in GitHub? Some computers do not have the internet, which is why I use the thumb-drive, but I get your point. Happy to check this out.

Comment: It doesn't need to be GitHub. That's just one popular public Git repository provider. You can create your own local repositories and servers. Git is its own program entirely separate from GitHub. The lack of internet access does make it tough though. You could keep a copy of the repository on the flash drive, make your changes locally, then push them from the flash drive the next time you're on a system with network access.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. It leaves out other people getting to use these files as well, especially if they don't have an account, but I see your point. Doesn't the problem still remain in pushing the files that were edited? That's the genesis of the whole idea.

Comment: The idea is that you keep a git repository on a server that anyone can read and authorized people can push changes to. You keep a copy of that repository on the USB drive. If you're working on a system with network access, you pull any changes others have made onto your USB drive before you start working, and push any changes you make back to the server when you're done. Take the drive to a non-networked machine and save your changes on the drive when you're done. Next time you're on a networked system, push the changes you made.

Comment: You keep the USB drive synced with the central repository whenever you're on a networked machine, and if the machine isn't networked, you keep your local changes on the USB drive until you have an opportunity to update the server. It doesn't leave anyone else out if you give them access to the central repository.